JPQL ignores Boolean param of joined entity field which is @Embedded
I have written JPQL query in repo to retrieve quiz with child questions which are not deleted. Deletion data is kept in @Embedded field Removal on entity. However the repository method keeps returning all questions (both with is_deleted = TRUE and FALSE). What is causing that behavior?
@Query("SELECT q FROM Quiz q LEFT JOIN q.questions s WHERE q.id = :id AND s.removal.isDeleted = FALSE ")
Optional<Quiz> findWQuestionsById(@Param("id") UUID id);

@Entity
@Table(name = "quiz")
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Quiz {

//ommited 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quiz", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<QuizQuestion> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Embedded
    @Builder.Default
    private Removal removal = new Removal();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "quiz_question")
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class QuizQuestion {

   //omitteed

    @Embedded
    @Builder.Default
    private Removal removal = new Removal();
}

@Embeddable
public class Removal {

    private Boolean isDeleted = false;

    public void remove() {
        if (isDeleted) {
            throw new WrongEntityStateException("Already removed");
        }
        isDeleted = true;
    }
}


the repository method keeps returning all questions - what does it actually mean? you query, as your stated, returns quizzes.
